# Getting Error when converting String to Date

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I am using FLEX 3.0 I want to convert string to Date. At first i just think its very easy for me but later its going to be very hard its a simple one but i can't convert that i have got an error. So please help me.

Hours in 24 hour format. if 7 hour than it shows 07. this one is same for minutes, seconds, date & month.

Here i am providing you the code that i have did till that time...

```
public function btn_click():void
{
    var str:String = lblDate.text;
    var d:Date = DateField.stringToDate(str,"YYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS");
    Alert.show(d.toString());
}

<mx:HBox height="5%" width="100%">
    <mx:Label id="lblDate" text="2011-12-07 11:06:01" />
    <mx:Button label="Click" click="{btn_click();}" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Please Help me as early as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html#stringToDate%28%29), the `stringToDate` method can only parse patterns containing Y, M, D and delimiter and punctuation characters. So by using H,M and S, you specify invalid characters in the pattern, which in turn determine the method to return `null`, that's why you get the error.

A more appropriate approach would be to use the `DateFormatter` class, as illustrated in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135829/date-to-string-string-to-date).

Hope this was useful. Have a good day.