# Converting a String into a Date object in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date to String <-> String to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135829/date-to-string-string-to-date)

I have a date in String form:

```
"Tue Sep 25 12:24:18 GMT+0530 2012"
```

How can I convert this String into a Date object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var d:Date = new Date();
d.setTime(Date.parse(str));
```